# How to check if user has scrolled to the end of items in the ListView

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to know if the user has scrolled to the end of the items in the ListView. I am developing in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Are you coding in c# or winjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link, it would help out you [Detecting when ListView is scrolled to the bottom](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled/)

Comment: A link is hardly ever a good answer. While yours probably answers the question, better would be if you had improved your answer. Remember that link may be broken in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using winjs you can use that code

```
var self = this;
document.querySelector(".win-vertical").onscroll = function () {
    if (self.endOfScroll(this) === true) {
        //do your stuff
    }
};

endOfScroll: function (element) {
    return element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
},
```

I use win-vertical for 'non-pivot' page.

If you use a pivot you can change it by '.win-pivot-item-content'

In c#

```
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}

// subscription:
GetScrollViewer(yourListView).ViewChanged += yourEvent_ViewChanged;
```